# How to safely echo all arguments of a script?

Tags: bash, echo

I am writing a bash script that must echo all of its arguments, which is surprisingly difficult to do.

The naive implementation looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$@"
```

However, that fails with input such as:

```
> ./script.sh -n -e -v -e -r
-v -e -r>
```

How can I make this more robust, such that the above results in:

```
> ./script.sh -n -e -v -e -r
-n -e -v -e -r
>
```

Comment: @Roadowl I was hopeful for a second, but that results in `-- -n -e -v -e -r`.

Comment: @Roadowl `echo` doesn't support `--`.

Comment: It seems you chose your arguments ;) from the `man echo` :  `-n     do not output the trailing newline` and `-e     enable interpretation of backslash escapes` are both arguments interpreted by `echo`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`echo` command's behavior may be different between systems. The safest way is to use `printf`:

```
printf '%s\n' "$*"
```

According to [posix](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html):

> **It is not possible to use `echo` portably** across all POSIX systems unless both `-n` (as the first argument) and escape sequences are omitted.
>
> The `printf` utility can be used portably to emulate any of the traditional behaviors of the `echo` utility ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use printf as well :

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "%s\n" "$*"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `printf` instead of `echo`:

```
#!/bin/bash

printf "%s " "$@"
printf "\n"
```

Comment: this would output one extra SPACE though it's invisible.

Comment: @pynexj. True, but does not much difference in this use case.

Answer (score 0):

This one adds a space in the beginning but is rather simple :

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "" "$@"
```